# I am working on a website with bootstrap4

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-4

[FORM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChoNX.png)

I am creating a form like this but i dont know how to place all radio buttons serially in a row. Could someone help me with this.

No. Of Guests 
                            
                          
                          1

```
                       <input type="radio" name="opt2" class="form-control" id="opt2">
                      <label for="opt1">2</label>

                      <input type="radio" name="opt3" class="form-control" id="opt3">
                      <label for="opt3">3</label>
                      <input type="radio" name="opt4" class="form-control" id="opt4">
                      <label for="opt4">4</label>
                      <input type="radio" name="opt5" class="form-control" id="opt5">
                      <label for="opt5">5</label>

                       </div>


              </div> 
            </form>
```

This is my code for the radio buttons.When i run this code all buttons are placed vertically.

please don't report this question. I am a noob on this platform so, i dont know exactly how it works.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code :

```
<div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input name="gruppo2" type="radio" id="radio4" checked>
      <label for="radio4">Opzione 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input name="gruppo2" type="radio" id="radio5">
      <label for="radio5">Opzione 2</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What change? if you use form-check-inline class input radio will display in one row.

Comment: Can you acept my answer?

Comment: Yes sure !! But i dont know how to do that

Comment: look left on my answer you can see an 'V' press and will be green, next up on that 'V' you can see a small arrow up and down press up arrow. thanks

Comment: done ?. it will not be publicly displayed, as i have less than 15 reputations.

Comment: i am not able to ask question, they said that i have to wait for 7 days. but i have small doubt. is there any other way to ask question here, or is there any other platform as good as this ? thanks

Comment: Don't worry, thanks for now, mmmh if is small problem ask here/edit your question.